# vb.net: how to control website with cefsharp

Tags: .net, cefsharp

I am using cefsharp in vb.net and trying to get the url of the actual page, check if document is empty and click a button by class, so how can I do?

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried? It helps if you can add some code and show that there was some effort put in before posting. If you are getting errors, including the stack trace also increases the chances of receiving answers.

Comment: You've included three very broad questions there, one of which you've already addresses. Can you provide some context? What exactly is `document is empty`?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this!

I've solved the url with:

```
Dim url As String = browser.Address
```

Tried to click a button by class:

```
browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-danger btn-lg  btn-block betButton').click()")
```

Last one not working and I have no idea how to check the document...

Comment: Have you tried executing your `javascript` in `Chrome DevTools` to verity it works? (`CefSharp` also has `DevTools` e.g. `browser.ShowDevtools()`. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/bae3c28e9231febcb620701bfbacae43299c4f5e/CefSharp/WebBrowserExtensions.cs#L562